# Initialized event of WPF UserControl not firing

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-3.5

I've got a very simple WPF UserControl that looks like this:

```
namespace MyUserControl
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
  {
    public UserControl1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
      Rect rect = new Rect(RenderSize);
      drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, new Pen(Brushes.Red, 1), rect);
      base.OnRender(drawingContext);
    }
  }
}
```

I then use it in the XAML of a standard WPF window like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="clr-namespace:MyUserControl;assembly=MyUserControl"
    Title="Window1" Height="351" Width="496">
    <Grid>
    <mc:UserControl1 Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="uControl1" Initialized="uControl1_Initialized"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

with the code behind of the above WPF Window looks like this:

```
private void uControl1_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
}
```

Unfortunately the Initialized event is never fired. Can anybody please tell me why?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.initialized.aspx) says

> This event will be raised whenever the
> EndInit or OnVisualParentChanged
> methods are called. Calls to either
> method could have come from
> application code, or through the
> Extensible Application Markup Language
> (XAML) processor behavior when a XAML
> page is processed.

I can reproduce your problem here. I would recommend using the `Loaded` event instead, which is fired after the control is laid out and rendered. If you really need the `Initialized` event, follow the advice of this [MSDN Forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/e987a889-9eca-4205-9ed7-5251dc31bebf/) and attach a event handler in the constructor of the `UserControl` before calling `InitializeComponent()` like this:

```
public UserControl1()
{
    this.Initialized += delegate
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
    };
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

For a more detailed explanation of `Loaded` vs. `Initialized`, see [this blog posting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mikehillberg/the-loaded-event-and-the-initialized-event).

Comment: Thanks David. Would you consider this a WPF defect?

Comment: No, reading the docs more thoroughly, I can see that this works as advertised.